# Sampling methods

Tags: sampling, survey

I have the following situation:

- I'm asking SMEs (small & medium enterprises) how they have reacted to situation ABC.
- Because I don't know who has encountered situation ABC, I ask all SMEs of one country (X).
- Only Y percent respond, because the others hadn't encountered this situation *or* didn't want to respond.

What was my sampling method?

I thought it would be *systematic sampling* because "each element in the population has a known and equal probability of selection". But I'm unsure.

Comment: Small and medium sized enterprises

Answer (score 1):

It is not systematic, because there are many reasons for not answering your question:

- I am too busy right now.
- I couldn't care less about this guy.
- My cat is sitting on top of the keyboard.

So far, we are independent. But it could also be:

- ABC is embarrasing, I don't want to admit it.
- As a consequence of ABC, I am too busy.
- I reacted badly to ABC and now I am in jail.
- ABC got me bankrupt, so I don't even show up in your database.

And, on the other hand:

- I am very proud of how I handled ABC and I want the world to know about it.
- As a consequence of ABC I lost a lot of clients, I don't have anything to do, so I will answer.
- ABC got me so much money I could hire a PR person that will happily answer your poll.

And of course, all the underlying possibilities:

- ABC is more/less likely to happen to companies about to go go bankrupt.
- ABC is more/less likely to happen to technological companies, that would be more/less willing to answer you than, say, car workshops.

So, answering this question in general is very difficult. If you can rule out some of this situations, you could build an underlying model that will allow you to weight different responses. Also, you may consider doing a more intensive poll locally, for example, sending someone to each and everyone of a sample of companies, and ensuring answers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Funny enough ABC could really cause all the proposed situations. I can't exclude any of them. I do have roughly 300 respondents and at the moment I don't have the resources to interview all of them. Do you think the above described process would be classified as a _convenience sampling_ then? I did some post-hoc tests to see whether my sample represents the initial population in a few variables and it looks ok...

Comment: You have 300 data points, that is great. Those are the people you don't need to interview, because they have already answered. Target the others and compare.

Comment: Also, your tests cannot probe the hidden variables that are a consequence of ABC.

Answer (score 1):

There's no sampling here, let alone systematic sampling, because you didn't sample anything, you asked "all SMEs". Random sampling takes place when the units to be studied are drawn from a frame, sometimes in multiple stages, with the aid of random numbers.  In the simplest form of systematic sampling, the the frame is ordered in some way; there is a random start; and every k-th element is selected.

Comment: It must be some kind of sampling if I end up with a sample!?

Comment: If you ask all SME of a single country, then you have taken a census of the population of the country, not a sample from the population of SMEs in the country.

Comment: You have a "sample" only in the loose usage of the term to describe a subset of the population who responded.  But you did no "sampling", meaning that you did not execute a sampling design, even by accident.  No random sampling selection algorithm = no random sample.

Comment: Is this not what is understood as "convenience sampling". I agree that it is not really a sampling in the sense of somehow representing the population with a given certainty, but because I end up with a sample of a population I am pretty sure there must be a terminology for that. I do understand the weaknesses of the method as pointed out by everyone.